# Multiple linear regression through orthogonal matrices

Tags: regression, linear-model, rotation, procrustes-analysis

An example of linear regression could look like:

$min \sum_{i=0}^{m}||x_i A - y_i||_2^{2}$, where ${x_i, y_i} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

I am interested in knowing how do I solve such problem with an of the following extra constraints, $A$ is an orthogonal matrix or $A$ is a rotation matrix.

Notice that a rotation matrix is orthogonal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is called the orthogonal Procrustes problem. You can find a closed form solution in terms of the SVD at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem.